# collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, ld

I'm trying to build [precimonious](https://github.com/corvette-berkeley/precimonious) on Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64. I allocated 1GB memory for it. My file structure looks like

```
~
|--- llvm/
|--- precimonious/
```

where the llvm is on version 3.0 as mentioned at https://github.com/corvette-berkeley/precimonious#requirement. Then I followed the steps on the README but command `make` ended with

```
...
llvm[1]: Linking Debug Shared Library libLLVM-3.0.so
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
compilation terminated.
...
```

I went through some answers online and they say it might because there's not enough memory to perform the link. But the memory usage is like
[image]

The gcc version on my machine is `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)` and was installed via `apt-get install build-essential`. This is a fresh droplet I just created on DigitalOcean btw. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

It is memory exhaustion.  The sampling interval for the memory measurement is just not small enough that it covers the exact point where the OOM killer kicks in.

Depending on the container/VM technology, you may be able to set `vm.overcommit_memory=2` before the build, so that the process is not killed (but doing so actually requires more memory and swap space to get the build to complete).

Comment: Though what actually helped was increasing the swap, this answer bring clarity with explanation on sampling interval. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem, and solved by:

- Increase `SWAP` disk (8 GB working with me).
- Increase Memory (I was on virtual machine, 8 GB).
- You need `27 GB` (LLVM 6.0.0) free disk space (check with `df -h` in Terminal).

Comment: I used this to increase the size of an existing swap file on Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/1177939/257860

Answer (score 7):

you can solve this issue by using :

```
 cargo run --release --verbose --jobs 1
```

Comment: Fixed it for me. Thanks.

Comment: For my EC2 instance where i wasn't sure i could easily change the memory settings, this was great.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes system kills linker due to CPU overload. If your build is parallel, try `-l` option (make and ninja support it). [Looks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336199/9027283) similar to your case.

To decrease system load, build release version of llvm. Linking of debug version is much more expensive.

> llvm[1]: Linking Debug Shared Library libLLVM-3.0.so

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error while installing snort on the Ubuntu inside a virtual box with 2 GB of RAM. I increased the RAM to 4 GB and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the lack of RAM that others have mentioned. But instead of increasing the RAM, you can add a swap with a few simple commands below and easily solve the problem:

```
fallocate -l 4G ./_swap.swap
mkswap ./_swap.swap
chmod 0600 ./_swap.swap
swapon ./_swap.swap
```