# Gem5 simulator installing scons build Error

Tags: ubuntu, scons, gem5

I got the below errors after compiling Gem5 simulator (downloaded from Gem5.org) on ubuntu 20.04 using VirtualBox.

what are these errors and how can I fix them, please?

the command is: scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j 4

```
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [build/X86/gem5.opt] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: You probably don't have enough RAM for the linker. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46259776/3052438

Comment: Try to set up SWAP / increase its size. You may also try to run `scons` without `-j 4`, to make sure no other build step runs at the same time as the linker.

Comment: It's pretty common for some larger builds to need 32 gigabytes or more of RAM. I've done some large builds on boxes with less memory and lots of swap space and it's painfully slow; I intend to put in 128 GB of physical RAM on my next builder.

Comment: I had already installed successfully earlier with 8 gb ram but now I'm getting error this time

Comment: Try `-j 2` and see if that changes things? Could be you're getting a bunch of large linking jobs running at same time.